# Ember nested routes but non-nested templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In an Ember app, is it possible to have nested routes but non-nested templates ?

Any examples for reference would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you can try [templateName](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/Route/properties/templateName?anchor=templateName). But I do not recommend to do such thing unless it is **absolutely needed**.